# Why does my parser incorrectly read a part, when changing another part?

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

I have these tokens defined in my `lex` file:

```
(?xi:
    ADC|AND|ASL|BIT|BRK|CLC|CLD|CLI|CLV|CMP|CPX|
    DEY|EOR|INC|INX|INY|JMP|JSR|LDA|LDX|LDY|LSR|
    NOP|ORA|PHA|PHP|PLA|PLP|ROL|ROR|RTI|RTS|SBC|
    SEC|SED|SEI|STA|STX|STY|TAX|TAY|TSX|TXA|TXS|
    TYA|CPY|DEC|DEX
) {
    yylval.str = strdup(yytext);
    for(char *ptr = yylval.str; *ptr = tolower(*ptr); ptr++);

    return MNEMONIC;
}

[\(\)=Aa#XxYy,:\+\-\<\>] {
    return *yytext;
}

\$[0-9a-fA-F]{4} {
    yylval.str = strdup(yytext);
    return ABSOLUTE;
}

\$[0-9a-fA-F]{2} {
    yylval.str = strdup(yytext);
    return ZEROPAGE;
}
```

and this is how I parse them in `bison`:

```
struct addr_offset {
    char *str;
    int offset;
};
%union {
    char *str;
    int number;
    struct addr_offset *ao;
}

%type<str> MNEMONIC
%type<str> ABSOLUTE
%type<ao> zp
%token ZEROPAGE

expression:
    MNEMONIC                                { statement(0,  $1, NULL,   "i"); }
|   MNEMONIC zp                             { statement(5,  $1, $2,     }
;

zp:
    ZEROPAGE { $$->str = strdup($1); }
|   '>' ABSOLUTE { $$->str = strdup($2); }
|   '<' ABSOLUTE { $$->str = strdup($2); }
;
```

Weird thing is, if I add the last two parts to the `zp` rule, the `MNEMONIC` is not read correctly in the `expression` rule.

Comment: Define ‘not read correctly’. NB Why are you strduping an strdup?

Comment: You're probably corrupting memory somehow.  The `$$->str` looks very suspicious as you never initialize `$$` to point at anything, so it is probably using an invalid pointer.

Comment: @ChrisDodd `$$` is provided. It doesn't need initalizing.

Comment: @user207421 If you don't assign anything to it, it contains whatever random garbage was in it from the last action that ran.  So every action that returns a `%type` must assign something to it.

Comment: @ChrisDodd Well I would have expected `$$.str = $1;` in the ZEROPAGE case, and `$$.str = $2;` in the other two cases. Not sure how this code even compiles. OP should show his `%union` declaration.

Comment: @user207421: Yes, without the details of the `%union` and `%type` declarations, we can't really say what is happening, but it is likely there's a `struct zp_info *zp;` or some such in the `%union` and a `%type <zp> zp` declaration.  Something like that is required to make this compile.

Comment: @ChrisDodd I added `%union` and `%type`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't set `$$` in a rule, bison will by default initialize it with the value of `$1`.  If that is a different `%type` than `$$` is expecting, bad things will happen.

In the case you are describing, it will likely be the value associated with the `<` or `>` token.  Since those tokens don't set `yylval` in the lexer code, it will be whatever happens to be there from the previous token -- in this case, the string allocated with `strdup` for `MNEMONIC`.  So when you assign to `$$->str`, it will treat the string as if it is a pointer to the data structure in question, and will overwrite 4 or 8 characters in the string with the pointer to another string that is being assigned there.

So the likely result will be some heap corruption which will manifest as bad/corrupted opcodes when you go to look at them.

---

So with the addition of the `%union`/`%type` declarations, we can see what is happening -- your're allocating a string and then treating the string's memory as a `struct ao`, which causes heap corruption and undefined behavior.

You need your actions that return a `struct ao` to actually allocate a `struct ao`:

```
zp:
    ZEROPAGE { $$ = malloc(sizeof(struct ao); $$->str = $1; }
|   '>' ABSOLUTE { $$ = malloc(sizeof(struct ao); $$->str = $2; }
|   '<' ABSOLUTE { $$ = malloc(sizeof(struct ao); $$->str = $2; }
;
```

Note that you *don't* need a strdup here, as the string has already been allocated in the lexer code, and you're just transferring ownership of that string from the token to the new `struct ao` you're creating.

You might want to encapsulation the creation of the ao object in a function:

```
struct ao *new_ao(char *addr) {
    struct ao *rv = malloc(sizeof(struct ao));
    rv->str = addr;
    rv->offset = strtol(addr, 0, 16);
    return rv;
}
```

then your actions just become eg, `{ $$ = new_ao($1); }`

Comment: Thanks. I added `yylval.str = strdup("")` in the lexer code and it works now. Still scratching my head on how the whole flex/bison works and where all those `strdup`'d values go.

Comment: @BartFriederichs They leak on every reduction unless you free them or assign them to `$$`.